# androidゲーム開発はeclipseよりunityのほうが効率いいですか？

Tags: android, unity3d, eclipse

またそれぞれ利点を教えてください。。。。

Comment: 何をもって「効率がよい」かの定義が必要です。ツール代という軸をもってくると、全て無料で収まるAndroid Studio(Eclipse)が良い　となりますよね。

Comment: unityでは無料版を使うつもりです。同じクオリティのゲームを作る際
eclipseとunityでは開発時間の効率の違いはありますか？　
例えば、ディフェンスゲームのようなある程度技術のいりそうなもの作る場合です。

Answer (score 3):

圧倒的にUnityを使った方が簡単で早いです。
Eclipseで０からゲームを作ろうと思ったら自分でUnity相当の機能を実装する必要があります。

Answer (score 2):

Eclipseでもunityでもマニュアルやヘルプを読んで、分からない等具体的な問題が発生してから聞くといいと思います。

googleはandroidStudioを薦めていますので、そちらも調べたほうが良さそうです。

ついでに「スタックオーバーフロー」のマニュアルも読んだほうがいいと思います。